# MySQL table doesn't exist

Tags: linux, mysql

What I did before the disaster was:

```
vi /etc/my.cfg
```

I added

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=4G
innodb_buffer_pool_instance=2
innodb_read_io_threads=12
innodb_write_io_threads=12
innodb_io_capacity=300
innodb_log_file_size=128M
```

and after that

```
$ service mysql stop
$ cd /var/lib/mysql
$ rm -f ibdata1 ib_logfile*
$ service mysql start
```

I receive `ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'db.table' doesn't exist` for every table.

My site is down, database backup does not help.

Comment: `database backup does not help` - Since you have almost destroyed your data you probably need to tell us what kind of errors you are getting when you try to restore.

Answer (score 7):

```
rm -f ibdata1 ib_logfile*
```

Well there's your problem. You deleted your INNODB table space.

You'll need to restore from backup.

Just curious: where did you get the idea that you should remove those files?